# Get categories name of basic column chart

Tags: highcharts

1)How can you I get categories name of basic column chart in highcharts .E.g. in this fiddle:
 **"jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/"**

I want all the categories name which are=>(jan,feb,march,april,may,june,july,aug,sept,oct,nov,dec) .

2) how can i get values of a specific categories like i want values of (Tokyo,newyork,london,berlin) for the month of december.

Comment: What you mean get the categories name? Where do you want them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xAxis categories for the first xAxis for the first chart can be returned with

```
Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].categories
```

Here's a real quick and dirty function that given a location and month will alert the y data value:

```
getSpecificData = function(location, month){
    var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
        if (chart.series[i].name == location){
            for (var j = 0; j < chart.series[i].points.length; j++){
                if (chart.series[i].points[j].category == month){
                    alert(chart.series[i].points[j].y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKPZz/).

Comment: An alternative using underscore: _(chart.xAxis).first().categories